# .htaccess file isn't removing the .html extension

Tags: html, .htaccess

Im quite new to this and would like to know why my code in the .htaccess file isn't removing the .html extension from each of the links in my nav bar, the live website can be seen at www.tekmillion.com

.htaccess code below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: yeah it seems to be okay in my end as well

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lies in that the expectation is that you have links using .html in your nav bar is supposed to redirect to friendly url. That's not how this rule works.

Your current rule allows you to use this type of URL `http://example.com/hello` in the browser and it will internally be rewritten to `http://example.com/hello.html`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

If you still have URL's like `http://example.com/hello.html`in your navbar, that rule will not do anything because the request is for `/hello.html` which is a `real` file.

So in order to redirect `http://example.com/hello.html` to the friendly version without html extension and to prevent use of .html, you need to add another rule. This is the complete rule you need to use.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#if someone enters URL with .html extension redirect to extensionless version
RewriteRule %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/(.+)\.html
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

#internally rewrite extensionless URL to .html file
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Let me know how this works out for you.